# Is there another way to debug UDP send buffer errors than netstat?

Tags: linux, linux-kernel, udp, debian-buster

I cant figure out why I am getting UDP send buffer errors. I am sending a ~5MB image over UDP via the RTPS protocol (Fast-DDS), but `netstat -s -u` is giving me the following output:

```
IcmpMsg:
    InType3: 14158
    InType11: 88
    OutType3: 14188
Udp:
    581757 packets received
    754 packets to unknown port received
    0 packet receive errors
    862941 packets sent
    0 receive buffer errors
    2296 send buffer errors
    IgnoredMulti: 4109
UdpLite:
IpExt:
    InMcastPkts: 13962
    OutMcastPkts: 13967
    InBcastPkts: 4109
    InOctets: 1803899484
    OutOctets: 1469914952
    InMcastOctets: 4496120
    OutMcastOctets: 4426432
    InBcastOctets: 320353
    InNoECTPkts: 1820538
```

I have 2296 send buffer errors, so I thought I would increase the UDP buffer sizes to the following settings:

```
net.core.rmem_default = 26214400
net.core.rmem_max = 26214400
net.core.wmem_default = 26214400
net.core.wmem_max = 26214400
net.core.somaxconn = 4096
net.core.netdev_max_backlog = 65536
net.core.optmem_max = 26214400
net.ipv4.udp_mem = 8388608 12582912 16777216
net.ipv4.udp_rmem_min = 16384
net.ipv4.udp_wmem_min = 16384
```

Unfortunately this does not do anything, and still gives send buffer errors.

Is there another way to debug this than using this `netstat -s -u` command?
Or should I look elsewhere for a fix? Can the problem be for instance at the receiving OS?

Setup:
Debian Buster <-(Ethernet)-> Debian Buster

Answer (score 0):

Turns out it is the following:
The standard `txqueuelen` of any ethernet adapter is set to a `1000`, so if you're filling the transmit queue with too much data, data will get dropped.

You can set the `txqueuelen` parameter with the following command:

```sh
ifconfig ${interface} txqueuelen ${size}
```

Size has to be between 1000 and 20000.
For me the command was the following:

```sh
ifconfig vnet0 txqueuelen 10000
```

You can find extra info on this topic in this small tutorial [here](https://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/gentoo-centos-rhel-debian-fedora-increasing-txqueuelen/).